# Dynamics 365: why I get "Xrm.Sdk WSDL" error for .net6 console client?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Mac OS, .Net6, C# 10.0.

I always created console clients for MS Dynamics 365 on .Net Framework Platform without problems. But now I need to do the same on .Net Core or newer platform (because I need to put it into Docker container later). At this case I try to use .Net6.

I created new console application and added the NuGet packages:

- `Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client` v0.6.6
- `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` v6.0.0
- `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` v4.9.0

My simple `Program.cs` file:

```
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;

namespace ConsoleAppExample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "CRM console client";

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var orgServiceUrl = "http://dev-crm-app02/MyCompany/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc";
            var crmUserLogin = "myLogin";
            var crmUserPassword = "myPassword"; 

            var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
            credentials.UserName.UserName = crmUserLogin;
            credentials.UserName.Password = crmUserPassword;

            try
            {
                using (var orgService = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(orgServiceUrl),
                           null, credentials, null))
                {
                    RetrieveVersionRequest versionRequest = new RetrieveVersionRequest();
                    RetrieveVersionResponse versionResponse =
                        (RetrieveVersionResponse) orgService.Execute(versionRequest);

                    WhoAmIRequest whoAmIRequest = new WhoAmIRequest();
                    WhoAmIResponse whoAmIResponse = (WhoAmIResponse) orgService.Execute(whoAmIRequest);

                    Console.WriteLine($"\nOrganizationService: {orgServiceUrl}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CRM version: {versionResponse.Version}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"User login: {crmUserLogin}");

                    Console.WriteLine($"\nOrganizationId: {whoAmIResponse.OrganizationId}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"BusinessUnitId: {whoAmIResponse.BusinessUnitId}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"UserId: {whoAmIResponse.UserId}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // Xrm.Sdk WSDL
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
                }

                Console.ResetColor();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER for exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run my application I get the error:

> Xrm.Sdk WSDL

Why does it happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Organization service client is deprecated and is not supported directly on net core.

When connecting using the dataverse serviceclient, connection string or serviceclient constructor is the only supported way.

That said onprem is not well supported due to the changes I the underlying authentication stack.

Best currently possible supported feature is to use oAuth via adfs on prem with a custom auth handler.

There is an extension written by a user of the dataverse service client that adds AD and WSTrust support for net core,  but it is not part of the MS distribution.

You can find a link to it on the dataverse serviceclient GitHub site issues board under the AD onPrem support topic
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatform-DataverseServiceClient/issues/110

Comment: Thank you. I will read about it and try to do.

Comment: Is it possible to create dataverse serviceclient, connection string or serviceclient constructor for NTLM Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to on-premises instance from .NET 6 using Dataverse Service Client if possible. If you want to connect using connection string:

1. You must have IFD configured.
2. You must have ADFS 2019.
3. You must use OAuth
4. You must have client application created at ADFS
5. As time of writing, there is a bug in DVSC and you may need additional configuration.

There is also possibility to connect if you are using ADFS 2016 using custom tokenProviderFunction.

Configuration is quite lengthy but written in detail at this article: [Using Dataverse Service Client to connect to OnPrem Dynamics 365 CRM (From .NET 6+)](https://dev.to/janisveinbergs/using-dataverse-service-client-to-connect-to-onprem-dynamics-365-crm-from-net-6-2ic4) along with code examples [on github](https://github.com/janis-veinbergs/DataverseServiceClientOnPremSamples).